# How to get dates between given dates in php 5?

Tags: php, date, php-5.4

Can any one give me a solution for finding dates between given dates without using `DATEINTERVAL` function of php?

i have tried so far:

```
$event_start_on='2013-09-01 01:06:00';
$event_expire_on='2013-10-01 01:06:00';
    $getdates=array();
                        $d=0;
                        if($rs->report_cycle=="Weekly"){
                            $takeinterval=new DateInterval('P7D');
                        }
                        else if($rs->report_cycle=="Biweekly"){
                            $takeinterval=new DateInterval('P15D');
                        }
                        else if($rs->report_cycle=="Monthly")
                        {
                            $takeinterval=new DateInterval('P30D');
                        }
                        else{
                            $takeinterval=new DateInterval('P1D');
                        }

                        $period=new DatePeriod($event_start_on,$takeinterval,$event_expire_on);
                        foreach($period as $dt){
                        $getdates[$d]=$dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                        $d++;
                        }
```

Comment: Did you even make an effort?

Comment: I actually have a solution that is neat and clean but I don't feel right posting it since you've made no effort to solve this yourself.

Comment: Why the stipulation of not using `DateInterval`? Can you explain what your problem was?

Comment: Given you've tagged PHP5.4, why can't you use DateInterval?

Comment: @JohnConde .I updated my question . please have look and provide me any other aleternative.

Comment: @WesleyMurch i already use it but its having a problem. running that code with cron job

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that doesn't use `DateInterval`

```
switch ($rs->report_cycle){
    case "Weekly": 
        $period = '+1 week'; break;
    case "Biweekly":
        $period = '+15 days'; break;
    case "Monthly":
        $period = '+1 month'; break;
    default: 
        $period = '+1 day';
}
$start = new DateTime('2013-09-01');
$end   = new DateTime('2013-10-01');
while ($start < = $end)
{
    echo $start->format("m/d/Y") . PHP_EOL;
    $start->modify($period);
}
```

Comment: i need weekly, biweekly , monthly dates between two dates interval.

Comment: Even though this is easy enough to edit yourself I have made that change for you. Hopefully this post is educational for you.